# How to customize pip's requirements.txt in Heroku on deployment?

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I'm deploying a Python Django app to Heroku, and I'd like to customize the requirements.txt file (by adding a git-backed dependency with password) only when I deploy to certain environments like Heroku. I'd love to set this in an environment variable or something, but I don't believe pip has any functionality like that. My idea was to use a hook that Heroku provides to place a script which would add to my requirements.txt before the dependencies are installed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can include a requirements file in another requirements file.

```
# requirements.txt    
-r requirements/base.txt

# requirements/base.txt
django==1.6

# requirements/heroku.txt
-r requirements/base.txt
djpostgresurlthing==1.0.0

# requirements/dev.txt
-r requirements/base.txt
django-debug-toolbar
```

I typically keep a `requirements.txt` file in the root of the project that just includes other requirements files(usually prod or a base) and make a `requirements/` folder with environment specific stuff. So locally I'd `pip install -r requirements/dev.txt` and on the server `pip install -r requirements/prod.txt`.

For your case with heroku, you need the root requirements.txt to be for heroku. So you can just use that file to include your heroku requirements file.

```
# requirements.txt    
-r requirements/heroku.txt
```

There's probably SOME way to tell heroku to use a different file. But this would be an easy way to get around it.

Comment: I should have specifically stated that the dependency customization I need to add includes a password, so I can't store this in the repo itself, but would use something like an environment var. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do standard HTTPS auth:

```
# requirements.txt
git+https://user:password@example.com/dir/repo.git
```

But a much cleaner way would be to host your own set of requirements, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#private-indexes

For managing different environment requirements, you can simply use `requirements.txt` for production and `requirements-dev.txt` for local development, or one of @yellottyellott's suggestions for including dependencies from other files.